# Infrared Camera Project: Is the following possible?

Tags: pi-3, networking, wifi, hardware, sensor

first post here/new raspberry pi user. I'd like to use the raspberry pi with the FLIR infrared camera in order to create a display-less security camera that will set a wireless alarm if a temperature above 100 degrees fahrenheit is identified in a room. Is this possible to do, and how could I go about it? Thank you in advance!!!

Comment: I should note that I would like the whole contraption to be battery powered as well. The camera which I plan on using is the lepton: https://lepton.flir.com/getting-started/lepton-quick-start-raspberry-pi/

Comment: I think the bottle neck might be how to detect more "red" stuff in the picture. I wonder if cheapie hardware RGB colour sensor and Rpi plus Esp32 WiFi controller is a much quick and dirty way than using advanced stuff like OpenCV etc.

Comment: Welcome to Raspberry Pi :-) But your question is too broad and opinion based. Such questions are flagged and may be closed. This site is made to do one specific question that can be answered detailed. And please don't add additional information in comments. Instead click the [edit](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/posts/106851/edit) link beneath the question and add it there. Please take the short [Tour](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/tour) and visit the [Help Center](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/help) to get an idea how things work here.